# PyQt A problem of wait() in QThread using moveToThread() method

Tags: python, concurrency, pyqt, qthread

I'm trying to write a multi-thread program with QThread in PyQt6.
The example code is below.
I create two threads by moveToThread() method and expect to join both of them after finish, but the result is crushing.
I know the other way is create subclass of QThread, it's easier to write, but I still want to understand why moveToThread() cannot do that.
Thank you!

```
import sys
import logging
from functools import partial
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt6.QtCore import *

logging.basicConfig(format="%(message)s", level=logging.INFO)

class MyWork(QObject):
  finished = pyqtSignal()
  def run_work(self, obj_name):
    # sleep 3 secs and finish
    for i in range(3):
      QThread.sleep(1)
      logging.info(f'{obj_name}: {i} sec.')
    self.finished.emit()

class MyWindow(QWidget):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setWindowTitle('MyWork Example')

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = MyWindow()
form.show()

# create two threads
th1 = QThread()
wo1 = MyWork()
wo1.moveToThread(th1)
th1.started.connect(partial(wo1.run_work, 'obj1'))
wo1.finished.connect(th1.quit)
th1.start()

th2 = QThread()
wo2 = MyWork()
wo2.moveToThread(th2)
th2.started.connect(partial(wo2.run_work, 'obj2'))
wo2.finished.connect(th2.quit)
th2.start()

# join two threads and finish
th1.wait()
th2.wait()
logging.info('All threads finished.')

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

the output:

```
obj1: 0 sec.
obj2: 0 sec.
obj2: 1 sec.
obj1: 1 sec.
obj2: 2 sec.
obj1: 2 sec.
```

Comment: Calling `wait()` will block the main thread, which means the event-loop won't start until the threads are finished. So just remove those two lines. If you want to print a message when the thread completes, connect a slot to its `finished` signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is caused by the fact that cross-thread signals call their connected functions in the thread of the receiver.

Remember that a QThread (just like a Thread object in python) is not "the thread", but the interface to access and run it.

When you do this:

```py
wo1.finished.connect(th1.quit)
```

the result is that `quit()` will be called in the thread in which `th1` was created, which is the main thread.

Since `wait()` blocks the event loop of the thread in which it was called, the call to `quit()` is *queued* and never processed.

For this specific case, the solution is to use a direct connection for the signal:

```py
wo1.finished.connect(th1.quit, Qt.DirectConnection)
# ...
wo2.finished.connect(th2.quit, Qt.DirectConnection)
```

By doing this, `quit()` will be called from the actual thread, allowing its immediate processing.

Note that yours is a very peculiar case that normally won't be used. You normally connect the worker "finished" signal to *both* `quit()` and `wait()` (in this specific order), or call those functions in the same order when you actually need to quit, or connect the QThread [`finished`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#finished) signal to the function that eventually will print the completion of the thread execution.